# is there a way to prevent a scheduled pipeline to execute again when a first execution hasnt ended?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that executes every hour and sometimes the execution takes more than an hour and the other execution starts, is there a way to prevent this? and for example the new execution to get queued?

thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have multiple build agents. Assuming you are using self-hosted build agents, you could specify certain **demands** of the agent to use only one agent. In this way, if the agent is not free, the build will keep waiting. To use a particular agent, add a demand of `Agent.Name equals agentname`, check the screenshot below. Agent name can be found in **capabilities** of the agent.

[image]

```
pool:
  name: MyPool
  demands:
  - myCustomCapability   # check for existence of capability
  - agent.name -equals agentname  # check for specific string in capability
```

Another way is triggering the pipeline via REST api and through the PowerShell task. You could use the REST API [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the detailed build info and check the latest build status:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&api-version=6.0
```

In the YAML, we could add a powershell task to get the build status, like:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType : inline
   script: |
     $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionID}&api-version=6.0"
     $connectionToken="Your PAT Here"
     $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

       $buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get


       $BuildStatus= $buildPipeline.value.status | Select-Object -first 1


       Write-Host This is Build Status: $BuildStatus
```

This list all the build status for the specify definitions, then use `Select-Object -first 1` to get the latest build status. If the status is `completed`, then queue the build. If the status is not `completed`, do not queue the build.

Comment: Thank you for your response, do you know any other way? :/ im asking because I wouldnt like to bind the process to a specofic agent because if another process is taking that agent then it would take forever to run, i know I seem like picky or something but just bare with me please haha in any Case if there is no other way then I would gladly mark your answer as correct! Thabk you once again

Comment: I see this as possible, I will work on this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, im sorry, the url you gave me is for builds (meaning the pipelines with completed execution) do you have the url for runs? :/

Comment: Could you elaborate "runs"? Stages? Jobs?